# Disabling double tap to zoom in Google Maps for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm working on an app (iOS 7) which is using Google Maps (v1.8.1). I'm trying to implement a feature, where You would have a polygon in the map, and when you double tap it - it zooms to the polygon. I've read around that I could disable zooming gestures in the map, via `googleMapView.settings.zoomGestures = NO;`, but I don't want to lose zoomGestures at all (You can zoom in using double tap (when not double tapping on the polygon) or pinch to zoom). I've tried adding a GestureRecognizer, but the method for the recognizer gets called after the zoom happens (GMSMapViewDelegate method willMove gets called first). How would I go about this?